# Text in an input field disappears after changing focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below jquery code that is supposed to create an effect like on codepen. To explain a little better, the page begins with one input box. The user fills that box with text and press "Enter" to spawn a second input box and then puts the cursor in that box.

```
ui_pc = 3001;
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("body").keydown(function(e){
    var press = e.which;
    press = press.toString();
    if(e.which=="13") {
      document.getElementById("main").innerHTML += "<div id=\"" + ui_pc + "\">"+ ui_pc+ " <input id=\""+ ui_pc+ "input\"></input></div>";
      document.getElementById(ui_pc+"input").select();
      ui_pc++;
    }
  });
});
```

When I run this, the next input box is created and the cursor moves. However, all the text in every input field is destroyed. Why is it acting this way, and how could it be fixed?

Edit: see code here http://schultheiss.io/lc3-web/

Comment: your demo code look to be working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this using jquery and `append()`, since you was updating your `.innerHTML` which was each time recreated. Also you can modify your code, and use `appendChild()` `DOM` method

```
var ui_pc=0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("body").keydown(function(e){
        var press = e.which;
        press = press.toString();
        if(e.which=="13") {
         $("#main").append( "<div id=\"" + ui_pc + "\">"+ ui_pc+ " <input id=\""+ ui_pc+ "input\"></input></div>"); 
         $('#'+ui_pc+"input").focus();
          ui_pc++;
        }

      });
 });
```

Check the below snippet

```js
var ui_pc = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").keydown(function(e) {
    var press = e.which;
    press = press.toString();
    if (e.which == "13") {
      $("#main").append("<div id=\"" + ui_pc + "\">" + ui_pc + " <input id=\"" + ui_pc + "input\"></input></div>");
      $('#' + ui_pc + "input").focus();
      ui_pc++;
    }

  });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <input type="text" placeholder="start typing">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, im taking a look now. 

edit: I see that once I've used jquery's append this fixes the problem. I suppose this is an issue with using js's innerHTML?

Comment: @Joshua Schultheiss yes, instead of  `innerHTML` you should use `appendChild()` method, if you want to accomplish that without jquery